# OOP PHP Undefined variables and empty query

Tags: php, mysql, oop, undefined

I'm trying to learn OOP PHP by querying a test databased. I tried googling the answer, but to no avail. Here's my code:

```
<?php

class DB {

        protected $db;
        protected $query;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test2");
            $this->query = "SELECT * FROM test";
        }


        public function querydb() {
            $this->db->query($db,$query);
        }

    }

    $database = new DB();
    $database->querydb();


?>
```

It says that the two variables defined in the constructor are not defined, and also that the query is empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: I understand the query($db,$query) part might be bad. If it is sorry this is like the fifth time I've rewritten this code.

Comment: Can you give us your exact error message?

Comment: Can you also show the code where you're initiating the DB class? Also the querydb() function should return the result of the query if you want to work further with it

Comment: @user2941726 Yes : `$this->db->query($this->db,$this->query);` You forgot `$this->` behind the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

> $this->db->query($db,$query);

To:

> $this->db->query($this->query);

Try this:

```
<?php

class DB {

        protected $db;
        protected $query;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test2");
            $this->query = "SELECT * FROM test";
        }


        public function querydb() {
            $this->db->query($this->query);
        }

    }

    $database = new DB();
    $database->querydb();


?>
```

Comment: `$this->db` also, not only `$this->query`

Comment: This got rid of all 3 error messages I've had. But now it says: **Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php on line 37;**

Comment: @user2941726 You'd better see docs (on php.net for example) for such errors.

Comment: Yes, you're passing in the `mysqli` instance as the first parameter, that's not right. It takes the query as the first arg.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use some undefined local variables in the querydb method. Replace them with class fields.

Replace:

```
public function querydb() {
    $this->db->query($db,$query);
}
```

with:

```
public function querydb() {
    $this->db->query($this->db, $this->query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function querydb() {
        $this->db->query($this->query);
    }
```

You should be referring to the query using `$this->query` instead of `$query`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public function querydb() {
            $this->db->query($db,$query);
        }
```

To

```
public function querydb() {
            $this->db->query($this->db,$this->query);
        }
```